# Does a mutex unlock when it comes out of scope?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Simple question - basically, do I have to unlock a mutex, or can I simply use the scope operators and the mutex will unlock automatically?

ie:

```
{ 
    pthread_mutex_lock (&myMutex); 
    sharedResource++; 
} // my mutex is now unlocked?
```

or should I:

```
{ 
    pthread_mutex_lock (&myMutex); 
    sharedResource++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&myMutex);
}
```

Comment: Which mutex implementation are you using?  Unless you're mutex implementation supports RAII, you will likely have to explicitly unlock the mutex.

Comment: Thanks @Void.  I'm using pthread.h.  Ie pthread_mutex_unlock() and pthread_mutex_lock().  What is RAII?

Comment: @AmitNayar: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization. It's probably the most important idiom in C++, since it's almost impossible to manage memory and other dynamic resources correctly without it.

Comment: You should edit your code to show you are using `pthread_mutex_lock`, etc. It's important. No one knows what `mutex_lock` is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The mutex is not going out of scope in your examples; and there is no way for the compiler to know that a particular function needs calling at the end of the scope, so the first example does **not** unlock the mutex.

If you are using (error-prone) functions to lock and unlock the mutex, then you will need to ensure that you always call `unlock()` - even if the protected operation throws an exception.

The best way to do this is to use a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) class to manage the lock, as you would for any other resource that needs releasing after use:

```
class lock_guard {
public:
    explicit lock_guard(mutex & m) : m(m) {mutex_lock(m);}
    ~lock_guard() {mutex_unlock(m);}

    lock_guard(lock_guard const &) = delete;
    void operator=(lock_guard &) = delete;

private:
    mutex & m;
};

// Usage
{
    lock_guard lock(myMutex);
    shared_resource++;
} // mutex is unlocked here (even if an exception was thrown)
```

In modern C++, use [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Using the RAII scope method is much better because it guarantees that the mutex will always be unlocked even in the face of exceptions or early return.

If you have access to C++11 though you might consider using a `std::atomic<int>` instead in which case you don't need to lock it to increment.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, **no the mutex will not be unlocked** when this code goes out of scope.

Mutex lockers following RAII use the fact that a destructor is automatically called when a non-heap allocated object goes out of scope. It then unlocks the mutex once the object that locked the mutex goes out of scope. In the case of your code, no object is allocated within the scope of the braces, so there is no potential for the mutex to be unlocked once the scope ends.

For example, using `QMutexLocker` from the Qt libraries, you can ensure that your mutex is unlocked when scope is ended:

```
{
    QMutexLocker locker(myMutex);
    if(checkSomething())
    {
        return;
    }
    doSomething();
}
```

This code is similar to:

```
{
    mutex_lock(myMutex);
    if(checkSomething())
    {
        mutex_unlock(myMutex);
        return;
    }
    doSomething();
    mutex_unlock(myMutex);
}
```

Although as Brian Neal points out, it does not safely handle the case where `checkSomething()` and `doSomething()` throw exceptions.

An alternative to Qt's `QMutexLocker` would be STD's [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: The two code snippets aren't equivalent if you consider exceptions. To make them equivalent you'd have to add try/catch blocks around `checkSomething` and `doSomething`. Just another reason to prefer your first example that uses RAII. :)

Comment: Good point, @BrianNeal. I've updated the answer. I make a point not to use exceptions, as they aren't really necessary with the `Qt` infrastructure, so I easily forget that others need to account for them.